# What does '!!' do in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the !! operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-operator-in-javascript)

Seen in jQuery's [ajax.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js) file (look near the bottom).

```
jQuery.support.ajax = !!jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr();
```

What does `!!` do? Isn't a double negative useless?